# Ubuntu + Copy Folder Remotely Either By Using SCP or Any Other Command

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer, scp

By using SCP Command, File is transfered from one system to remote system. But I want to transfer whole folder from local system to remote system. So How it can be possible.

Please help me out ?

Answer (score 3):

> scp -r
>   user@remote.server:/path/to/directory/at/remote/server
>   local_destination_dir

will do the trick. scp will follows symlinks encountered in the tree traversal.

Comment: If it's a big directory and changes with any frequency then you might want to look at rsync which will only copy the changed files. If it's small then stick with Pawel's scp -r.